# Регулярные выражения python

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

```
patres = re.findall(ur"[а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\_\-\+=\[\]\{\};:\'\"\\<>,\./?√ ]", message, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Как проверить, содержит ли строка другие символы помимо указанных?

Comment: добавить другие символы в `[а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\_\-\+=\[\]\{\};:\'\"\\<>,\./?√ ]`

Comment: Поставьте отрицание `[^а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\_\-\+=\[\]\{\};:\'\"\\<>,\./?√ ]` и будите искать символы отличающиеся от указанных.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте исключающий символьный класс путём добавления `^` в начале класса:

```
non_patres = re.findall(ur"[^а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]{};:'\"\\<>,./?√ -]", message, flags=re.UNICODE)
                            ^
```

В данном случае этот знак означает *найди любой символ, отличный от тех, что перечислены внутри данного класса*.

Также нелишним будет удаление лишних обратных слешей. Знак `-` можно не экранировать, если он стоит в самом конце символьного класса.